# Javascript : How to get the last two characters typed into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, textarea

**What is the best way to grab the last two characters typed into a textarea box?**

I need the last 2 characters typed NOT the last two characters of the overall string.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo of doing it with jQuery, while displaying the last two characters that were entered: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/5gUHb/

And the source:

```
var keys = [];
$('#target').keypress(function(e) {
    keys.unshift(e.which);
    update();
});

function update() {
       $('#last')
           .prepend($('<li/>').text(String.fromCharCode(keys[0])))
           .children(':eq(2)').remove();
}
```

This demo captures the keypress event on the text area, unshifts the value onto the array (because then the indexes are representative of the number of keys that have been pressed since that key was pressed) and then updates the display.

The display update simply pushes the first value from the array to the top of a `<ul>` and removes the child (if any) at index 2 in the list.

<del>Note additionally that because of the way jQuery deals with `.keypress()`, you do NOT have to filter out modifier or arrow keys.</del>

**UPDATE**
Please see Tim Down's comment to my answer for an explanation of what filtering should take place.  My initial note was mistaken, based on a quick test in Chrome.

Comment: Actually you do have to filter out non-printable keys. Which keys produce `keypress` events varies between browsers. For example, Firefox produces `keypress` events for most non-printable keys, and jQuery will supply a `which` value of 0 for most of them, although there are exceptions such as backspace which produces a `which` value of 8. There are other variations, and I'd suggest referring to http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for full details. jQuery itself hides very little of the complexity.

Comment: @Tim - Thank you for pointing that out, I have updated my answer to refer people to your comment.

Answer (score 6):

You need to catch the `keypress` event on the textarea and then keep a log of keys that were pressed.  Note that this is going to catch arrow keys, shift, alt, etc so if you just want characters you need to filter them out.

Simple example:

```
var keyPresses = [];
textarea.onkeypress = function(ev){
   ev = ev || window.event;

   var key = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
   keyPresses.push(key);
}
```