# How to get when user press 'W' with 'shift'

Tags: javascript, jquery, keylistener

I want to know when user press <kbd>W</kbd> with <kbd>shift</kbd>. I am not getting any logic for this. Kindly suggest.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('body').keydown(function(e) {
                var key= e.keyCode;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test">test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: play here to get char codes http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Have you simply tried testing the character returned instead of the keycode?  [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464084/javascript-how-to-get-the-last-two-characters-typed-into-a-textarea).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>W</kbd> has key code `87`, while jQuery [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object has `.shiftKey` flag:

```
if (e.which === 87 && e.shiftKey) { ... }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/etgAB/

Comment: @amit You can read the chapter `Event Properties` in the [*docs*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). All important properties are listed there. Except `.shiftKey` the `event` object contains `.altKey`, `.ctrlKey`, and many other useful flags.

Answer (score 3):

You should have `true` in the `event` object at `e.shiftKey`, besides of the keycode of `W` (87)

Learn more about the jQuery-normalized event object at the [official docs page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)