# If the last 2 characters typed are /c then do this jquery

Tags: jquery, string

I am trying to modify [**`this example`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464084/javascript-how-to-get-the-last-two-characters-typed-into-a-textarea) but I am having a hard time to get the last 2 characters in a variable so I can see if the user typed `/c`.

```
var keys = [];
$('#target').keypress(function(e) {
    keys.unshift(e.which);
    $('#last')
           .prepend($('<li/>').text(String.fromCharCode(keys[0])))
           .children(':eq(2)').remove();
});
```

I can't figure out how to get this part into a variable so I can check it

```
$('#last')
       .prepend($('<li/>').text(String.fromCharCode(keys[0])))
       .children(':eq(2)').remove();
```

I understand this is prepending `<li>` but I need to just store it in a simple variable.

Ultimately I need my `if` statement to trigger when the last 2 characters typed by a user are `/c`.

```
if (somevariable == '/c') {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(keys[0]))` to save it into a string and check if it matches your string then do whatever you want and then check if the length is 2 then reset the string.

```js
var keys = [];
var input = [];
var findString = '/c';

$('#target').on('keypress', function(e) {
  keys.unshift(e.keyCode || e.which);
  updateN();
});

function updateN() {

  //push into the input array
  input.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(keys[0])));

  //check if input is of valid length to be searched for string 
  if (input.length >= findString.length) {
    //if last 2 keys match the string to be found 
    var keyFound = (input[input.length - 2] + input[input.length - 1]) == findString;
    //if string found
    if (keyFound) {
      console.log("/c detected");
    }
    if (input.length > 20) {
      //reset the array but keep last 2 indexes to keep the track of the pressed keys
      input.splice(0, input.length - 2);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="target">
```

---

@Tim Down You do have to filter out non-printable keys Which keys produce keypress events varies between browsers. For example, Firefox produces `keypress` events for most non-printable keys, and jQuery will supply a which value of `0` for most of them, although there are exceptions such as backspace which produces a which value of 8. There are other variations, and I'd suggest referring to [**`unixpapa.com/js/key.html`**](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) for full details. jQuery itself hides very little of the complexity

Comment: for some reason `/` comes up as `¿` and all the letters are coming in capitalized. `¿C`

Comment: which browser ? @CesarBielich

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: thats strange i also have chrome `Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)` yours ?

Comment: Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I get that but for some reason my browser is showing those other special characters

Comment: check again now does it show you `I got you` when you type in `/c` @CesarBielich

Comment: Same issue as before

Comment: check now @CesarBielich

Comment: Nothing is happening, I am going to be back in 15 and I can check again

Comment: well that is strange as it works for me in FF too you might have to double check in some other browser, to see if it is a browser issue, or wait for someone else to land here

Comment: I figured it out, when I changed my event to `keypress` instead of `keyup` it worked. I had changed it to keyup at some point and forgot I did that. Thanks

Comment: lol :D i was going crazy what it could possibly be @CesarBielich glad it worked.